# apc_define_constants vs hidef vs define

Tags: php, performance

Has anyone used apc_define_constants or hidef vs using define. Any true benefits or possible bugs in the latest versions?

apc-define-constants - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-define-constants.php

hidef - http://pecl.php.net/package/hidef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `apc_define_constants` quite a bit without any trouble - I've never tried hidef because of its 'alpha' status.

Comment: Not for me, no - but define() was never my bottleneck.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an oldy, but since it comes up high in both SO's own search engine and Google:
a nice article about the relative performance of the methods mentioned by the OP can be found here: http://shwup.blogspot.com/2010/04/about-constants.html

Answer (score 0):

We've been using hidef for three years in a production environment, and once you get used to the quirks of the hidef ini files, and defining arrays in hidef, it's awesome, stable, and simple to use.